# Overriding Jquery Mobile styles

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, user-interface

Im working on a small mobile splash so ive imported the jquery and now trying to change the css.  Anything I change isnt changing the styles.  The js files are loaded from web while Im putting the new styles inline.  Im using the !important declaration but still nothing is changing.  Is it because by the time it loads in the browser it is overriding my local css?  Background of header and footer are black and use "data-role=header" but chaging style is getting changes in dreamweaver but when I load it its not there so its like when it loads the online files it replaces my code.  Anyway to override this to display my inline css?  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Please, make sure that you try to change style for the dom element you are looking for.

#### Example

Your source:

```
<a data-role="button" id="lg-login-btn" class="lw-button">Walk In</a>
```

What source code is generated:

```
<a data-role="button"id="lg-login-btn" class="lw-button ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-  all ui-btn-up-a" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="a">
     <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
          <span class="ui-btn-text">Walk In</span>
     </span>
</a>
```

Firebug and other dev tools will help you to examine elements and their styles.
If you will use **!important** annotation for overriding jquery-mobile styles, it should work fine.

Also you can visit this **[link](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/api/themes.html)** to look how to customize your styles using JQM theme framework.

Answer (score 0):

we can override the JQM styles by following the cascading order while including the css files in a page. Initially Jquery mobile should be included after that you have to keep your style sheet.

To check whether modified styles are getting applied or not using Firebug or developer toolbar in chrome.

Please refer below link to know how to override the customizes themes in jquery mobile:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/api/themes.html